# ¿Como recuperar valores de una tabla muchos a muchos con Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

Estoy intentando recuperar valores de una base de datos usando Hbernate, el problema es que no logro hacer funcionar la consulta en HQL, pero si en SQL, a continuación les dejo los datos de lo que tengo:

Mi base de datos tiene las siguientes tablas:

1. persona
2. casa
3. seguro

---

Las siguientes tablas intermedias:

1. casa_seguro

---

Y las relaciones son:

1. Una persona puede tener muchas casas, pero una casa solo puede pertenecer a una persona. (1:N).
2. Una casa puede tener muchos seguros, y un seguro puede estar en mas de una casa. (N:M).

---

Ahora necesito poder recuperar los nombres de todos los seguros que tiene una casa, pero usando el id de la persona como parámetro de búsqueda. En query SQL existen varios metodos, incluso hasta una búsqueda cruzada como la siguiente muestra los datos por pantalla:

> SELECT s.nombre FROM seguro s, persona p, casa c, casa_seguro cs WHERE p.idp = c.idp AND c.idc = cs.idc AND cs.ids = s.ids AND p.idp = 2;

Sin embargo, no logro hacer que la misma consulta funcione en Java con HQL, busqué en guias de internet pero suelen usar ejemplos de una sola tabla, y la documentación de Hibernate se me hace muy confusa. Aqui el código en Java que he hecho:

```
public void mostrarSeguros(int identificador){
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT s.nombre "
                                    + "FROM Seguro as s "
                                    + "INNER JOIN CasaSeguro as cs WITH cs.ids = s.ids "
                                    + "INNER JOIN Casa as c WITH c.idc = cs.idc "
                                    + "INNER JOIN Persona as p WITH p.idp = c.idp "
                                    + "WHERE p.idp = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", identificador);
    List<Seguro> seguros = query.list();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    for (Seguro seguro : seguros) {
       System.out.println(seguro.getSeguronombre());
    }

}
```

Código de la clase Seguro:

```
public class Seguro  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int ids;
 private String nombre;
 private Set casaseguros = new HashSet(0);

public Seguro() {
}


public Seguro(int ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
}
public Seguro(int ids, String nombre, Set casaseguros) {
   this.ids = ids;
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.casaseguros = casaseguros;
}
getters y setters.
```

Código de la clase Casa

```
public class Casa  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int idc;
 private Persona persona;
 private String material;
 private Set casaseguros = new HashSet(0);

public Casa() {
}


public Casa(int idc) {
    this.idc= idc;
}
public Casa(int idc, Persona persona, String material, Set casaseguros) {
   this.idc = idc;
   this.persona = persona;
   this.material = material;
   this.casaseguros = casaseguros;
}
Getters y Setters.
```

Comment: Te falta añadir las clases de Casa y Seguro. La tabla intermedia no es necesaria tenerla como parte del modelo

Comment: ¿Donde debo de añadir las clases?, si hablas de mapear las tablas como clases ya esta hecho, el inconveniente es con la Query de HQL.

Comment: Me refería a añadir el código a la pregunta

Comment: Añadí el código de las clases que dihiste a la pregunta. No añadi los Getters y Setters para que sea mas cómodo de leer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo habitual en estos casos es lo siguiente:

```
public class Casa  implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    private int idc;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idP") //Asumo que tienes en la clase Persona un id con ese nombre
    private Persona persona;


    private String material;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name = "casa_seguro", 
      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idS") }, 
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idC") }
    )
    private Set seguros = new HashSet(0);

    ...
}
```

De este modo, tienes en Casa la lista de seguros, haciendo la unión sencilla.

Un detalle importante es que aquí hemos declarado la forma de unir ambas tablas en ambos sentidos. por lo que en la clase Seguro basta con poner algo como:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "seguros")
private Set casas;
```

Si en lugar de usar anotaciones, estás configurando mediante XML, tienes el equivalente [aquí](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/).

Entonces lo que puedes es una consulta así:

```
select s.nombre from Casa c join c.seguros s where c.persona.idp =:idPersona
```

Comment: En sí el código que publicaste, junto al enlace, tienen un gran valor considerando mi proyecto, pero me surge una duda, ¿Cómo esto resuelve el tema de la consulta HQL?. ¿Al designarle la unión permitirá aplicar la query?.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener los seguros de una casa o los seguros de una persona (incluyendo todas las casas que tiene)?

Comment: Todos los seguros de una casa, pero la búsqueda se realiza por el id de una persona. Ej: Ingreso el id: 12-5, ese id esta relacionado con la casa n°498, y esa casa tiene "Seguro contra incendios" y "Seguro contra derrumbes". Entonces si yo ingreso el valor 12-5 el método me imprime los seguros de incendios y derrumbes. Cuando lo realizo por SQL funciona, pero no por HQL. Esa es la duda que intente plasmar en la pregunta

Comment: Te he añadido la query necesaria